# How do you use maxInstructionCount in HLSL

Tags: c#, xna, hlsl

I have an HLSL shader I'm using in an XNA application and would like to change the maxInstructionCount but am unsure how to implement do it.  I'm using ps_2_0.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Above the shader function you want to apply the attribute to, you would do:

```
[maxInstructionCount(100)] 
float4 YourFunction()
{
}
```

Comment: When I try it I get the following error: "warning X3554: unknown attribute maxInstructionCount, or attribute invalid for this statement"

Comment: @AaronBenzel Hmmm, apparently this attribute is only available if you are developing for Xbox 360.  Are you targeting XBox360 in your project?

Comment: No it's a windows based app that simply uses the GPU for graphics processing.

Comment: @AaronBenzel Then you cannot use this attribute.  The compiler will not allow it unless it is targeting xbox 360.